# How to improve performance or simplify .NET code with linq

Tags: performance, linq, .net-4.0

Apart from database operation, how can I simplify or improve my code with LINQ ?

**Example**
    *To search in a string*

```
 string search = "search in list";
    IEnumerable<string> results = myList.Where(s => s == search);
```

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question with that example?

Comment: @SLaks As I am completely new in LINQ, I thought to ask a question how good developers like you take benefit of LINQ while coding. I just put an example which I randomly find on internet

Comment: Keep in mind you rarely improve *performance* with LINQ. On the contrary! LINQ may simplify how your code looks and is read (by humans), but in my experience code is slowed down considerably when you use LINQ instead of traditional loops.

Comment: @Pedery Thanks for your input, I will now test performance also. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use LINQ statements in for loops. As a simple example instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] > 10)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I might do this:

```
foreach(var value in array.Where(item => item > 10))
{
    ...
}
```

I frequently find myself needing to get the first occurrence of a value in a list:

```
var first = orders.FirstOrDefault(order => order.Items.Count > 1);
```

Comment: Don't use count when your just looking for the existence of an Item.  Any() will short circuit the call when the first row is found.  Count will Iterate though all items.  Therefore Any() is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

With something this simple why not just see if it exists..

```
myList.Any(s => s == search) //which would return a boolean.
```